# How to verify event subscribed using Moq

Tags: unit-testing, silverlight-4.0, moq

I am using MVVM pattern and silverlight 4.0 and Moq for testing.
In the view model constructor, am passing an IEventAggregator object. This object is used to subscribe to an event called SelectionChangedEvent.

In the test method I am doing like this:

```
this.selectedEvent = new Mock<SelectionChangedEvent>();
this.eventAggregator.Setup(x => x.GetEvent<SelectionChangedEvent>()).Returns(this.selectedEvent.Object);
var viewModel = new ViewModel(this.eventAggregator);
```

I want to test that the event is getting subscribed when the constructor is called.
How can I verify this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Disclaimer: I haven't been able to test this under Silverlight]

Here's a possible solution that basically executes a callback to set an external boolean when Subscribe is called on the event. See comments below though.

```
[Test]
public void Constructor_CallsSubscribeOnSelectionChangeEvent()
{
  var subscribeCalled = false;
  var selectedEvent = new Mock<SelectionChangedEvent>();
  var eventAggregator = new Mock<IEventAggregator>();

  selectedEvent
    .Setup(x => x.Subscribe(
      It.IsAny<Action<object>>(),
      It.IsAny<ThreadOption>(),
      It.IsAny<bool>(),
      It.IsAny<Predicate<object>>()))
    .Callback<Action<object>, ThreadOption, bool, Predicate<object>>
      ((action, option, f, pred) => { subscribeCalled = true; });

  eventAggregator
    .Setup(x => x.GetEvent<SelectionChangedEvent>()).Returns(selectedEvent.Object);

  var viewModel = new ViewModel(eventAggregator.Object);

  Assert.That(subscribeCalled, Is.EqualTo(true));
}
```

The above is pretty ugly, mostly due to the fact the the only mockable (virtual) overload of the Event's Subscribe method takes four arguments and that the argument types of Callback() can't be deduced automatically - which leads to lots of "extraneous" code.

An alternative would be to instead mock EventBase.InternalSubscribe, which only takes a single argument; but as that method is protected this approach has its own caveats.

Comment: This isn't working for me, I get the error System.ArgumentException: Invalid callback. Setup on method with parameters (Action`1,ThreadOption,Boolean,Predicate`1) cannot invoke callback with parameters (Action`1,ThreadOption,Boolean,Predicate`1).